# Unable to properly configure UIScrollView (Offset on top)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have been fighting with this all morning and can't seem to find a solution. I have created a `UIImageView`, filled it with red, then added it to a `UIScrollView` and set the `contentSize` to the size of the `UIImageView`. If I print the `contentOffset` i see `(0, 0)` and if I print the `contentSize` and the `UIImageView.frame.size` they are the same but the red "image" always appears smaller than what the `scrollView` thinks the `contentSize` is.

If I scroll all the way to the top I see a cyan stripe about 100 pixels high above the red image and the scroll bar will not make it all the way to the top of what I believe the top of my scroll view to be. Although the top of the scroll bar does line up with the top of my red window so it would seem as though the scroll view is confused as to where it actually lives. Or more likely, I'm confused

[image: IMG]

Here is my what seems like very simple code...

```
    imgHorizon = UIImage.init(named:"horizon")!
    imgBezel = UIImage.init(named:"bezel_transparent")!
    imgWings = UIImage.init(named:"wings_transparent")!

    imgViewHorizon = UIImageView.init()
    imgViewBezel = UIImageView.init()
    imgViewWings = UIImageView.init()

    svHorizon = UIScrollView.init()

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    imgViewHorizon = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgBezel.size.width, height: imgHorizon.size.height))
    imgViewHorizon.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    imgViewBezel = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgBezel.size.width, height: imgBezel.size.height))
    imgViewBezel.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
    imgViewBezel.clipsToBounds = true
    imgViewBezel.image = imgBezel

    imgViewWings = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgBezel.size.width, height: imgBezel.size.height))
    imgViewWings.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
    imgViewWings.clipsToBounds = true
    imgViewWings.image = imgWings

    svHorizon = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgBezel.size.width, height: imgBezel.size.width))
    svHorizon.contentSize = CGSize(width: imgBezel.size.width, height: imgHorizon.size.height)
    svHorizon.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
    svHorizon.bounces = false
    svHorizon.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    svHorizon.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    svHorizon.addSubview(imgViewHorizon)
    addSubview(svHorizon)
    addSubview(imgViewBezel)
    addSubview(imgViewWings)
```

Comment: For fast diagnoses please tell where have you written this code in your `ViewController`? In the `Attributes Inspector` of your `ViewController` uncheck the `Adjust Scroll View Insets`.

Comment: I wrote it in a class which inherits from UIView. This code is in the `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method. In interface builder i dropped a UIView on my viewcontroller and set the class to my custom class

Comment: Override the `layoutSubviews` method and set the frames of your `imageViews` there. And did you uncheck the `Adjust Scroll View Insets`?

Comment: @Adeel All I did was check Adjust Scroll View Insets and it started to behave. I'll look into the other thing you suggested. Just started learning this stuff last night.

Comment: You mean the problem disappeared when you unchecked that `Adjust Scroll View Insets` option? If yes then I'll post it as an answer because many others will benefit from it too.

Comment: @Adeel Yes, please post as an answer. That was all I needed to do and never would have found that on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments it turns out that the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` option was checked in the attributes inspector of the `ViewController`. Unchecking it resolved the problem. Have a look at the image below. You need to uncheck the highlighted option.

[image: Attributes of the View Controller]